# Why when specifying the width margin-right is invalid?

Tags: html, css

1)When me specifying the width margin-right is invalid(only in position is 'static')?

```
<style type="text/css">
    body{
        border:1px solid #808080;
        width:500px;
        height:500px;
    }
    div {
        border: 1px solid #0094ff;
        width: 200px;
        /*margin-left:50px;*/ /* ok */
        /*margin-top:50px;*/ /* ok */
        margin-right: 50px; /* invalid,not working ?*/
        margin-bottom: 50px; /* invalid,not working?*/
    }

</style>
<body>
   <div>test div</div>
</body>
```

2)Why when me remove the width of div, the margin-right will take effect?

3)Why when me remove the height of body, the margin-bottom will take effect?

What this CSS in the default layout in matching margin-right and margin-bottom rule is that?

My mean is **the div position is' static'** and **do not use' float' property**.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is fine and valid. However, to see the effects you are trying to apply, you need to add more elements to compare.

Adding a `margin-bottom` means that elements under your `div` will be pushed down. Same width `margin-right`: elements next to your `div` will be pushed to the right side.

To demonstrate your webpage, I added 3 more `divs` which are floated so you could see how the margin affects the right and bottom sides:

```css
body {
  border: 1px solid #808080;
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
}
div {
  border: 1px solid #0094ff;
  width: 150px;
  margin-right: 50px;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div>Lorem.</div>
<div>Officiis.</div>
<div>Asperiores.</div>
<div>Enim.</div>
```